# Do we have $C_0(\mathbb{R}) \cong \{f \in C(S^1): f(1)=0\}$?

Tags: operator-theory, c-star-algebras

This question might be nonsense, but do we have an isomorphism of $C^*$-algebras
$$C_0(\mathbb{R}) \cong \{f \in C(S^1): f(1)=0\}$$
where $S^1$ is the unit circle?  I can't think of any obvious map from one to the other $C^*$-algebra.

Comment: By $C_0(\Bbb{R})$, do you mean the space of continuous maps that tend to $0$ at $\pm\infty$? If so the answer ought to be yes, through identification of $S^1$ with the one point compactification of $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Yes, that's what it means.

Comment: Any continuous function $\newcommand{\R}{\Bbb{R}}\R\to\R$ that vanishes at $\pm\infty$ uniquely extends to a continuous function $S^1\simeq\R^+\to\R$ which vanishes at the point at infinity. Extension / restriction yield inverse isomorphisms of $C^*$-algebras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  If $H$ is any homeomorphism of $S^1 \setminus \{1\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, you get a map of $C^*$-algebras
$$\Theta:C_0(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \{f∈C(S^1):f(1)=0\}$$
defined by $\Theta (g)=g \circ H$.